# android finalizing a cursor that has not been deactivated or closed

Tags: android

It seems that i cant fix this error msg.
I close the cursor correctly.. i tried even to create a new cursor with different reference name.. but this didnt work too.. what do i do wrong?

12-17 10:09:14.107: E/Cursor(277): Finalizing a Cursor that has not been deactivated or closed. database = /data/data/com.lernapp.src/databases/LernApp, table = Answers, query = SELECT Answer, Correct FROM Answers WHERE TestId = ? AND TestPageId = ?

```
private void getRowData(LernAppOpenHelper myDbHelper) {
        String[] columnsTestPage = {"TestPageId", "Question","Picture"};
        Cursor cursor = myDbHelper.getQuery("TestPage", columnsTestPage, "TestId = ?", new String[]{testNummer}, null, null, null); 
        startManagingCursor(cursor);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        while(!cursor.isAfterLast()){   
            int testPageId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("TestPageId"));
            String question = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Question"));
            String picture = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Picture"));

            this.testPages.add(new TestPage(testPageId, question, picture));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        columnsTestPage = null;

        String[] columnsAnswers = {"Answer", "Correct"};

        for(TestPage p: testPages){
            cursor = myDbHelper.getQuery("Answers", columnsAnswers, "TestId = ? AND TestPageId = ?", new String[]{testNummer, p.getTestPageId()}, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while(!cursor.isAfterLast()){
                String answer = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Answer"));
                int correct = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("Correct"));
                p.setAnswer(answer, correct);
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }           
        }   

        cursor.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you use `startManagingCursor(cursor);` there's no need to close the cursor, Android will do it for you.
Either remove `startManagingCursor(cursor);`, or remove `cursor.close();` references.

**EDIT:**
Try this:

```
private void getRowData(LernAppOpenHelper myDbHelper) {
        String[] columnsTestPage = {"TestPageId", "Question","Picture"};
        Cursor cursor = myDbHelper.getQuery("TestPage", columnsTestPage, "TestId = ?", new String[]{testNummer}, null, null, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while(!cursor.isAfterLast()){   
            int testPageId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("TestPageId"));
            String question = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Question"));
            String picture = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Picture"));

            this.testPages.add(new TestPage(testPageId, question, picture));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        columnsTestPage = null;

        String[] columnsAnswers = {"Answer", "Correct"};

        for(TestPage p: testPages){
            cursor = myDbHelper.getQuery("Answers", columnsAnswers, "TestId = ? AND TestPageId = ?", new String[]{testNummer, p.getTestPageId()}, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while(!cursor.isAfterLast()){
                String answer = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Answer"));
                int correct = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("Correct"));
                p.setAnswer(answer, correct);
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
            cursor.close(); // Close the cursor here before the next loop
        }   
    }
```

Comment: this doesnt change anything.. if i just use startManagingCursor or cursor.close(), the same error msg appears..